# Having trouble with eval() with React, it won't actually evaluate the string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build the calculator from Freecodecamp's front end projects.  And I am using the `eval()` function with pressing the equals button.

Here is the child component

```
    class Equals extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleEquals = this.handleEquals.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleEquals = () => {
    this.props.handleClick(eval(this.props.exp))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button id='equals' onClick={this.handleEquals}>=</button>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is the parent component

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numPad: numPad,
      operations: operations,
      prevVal: [],
      currVal: '',
      display: '',
      expression: []
    }
    this.handleDisplay = this.handleDisplay.bind(this);
    this.clearDisplay = this.clearDisplay.bind(this);

  }
  
  handleDisplay = input => {
    
    this.setState({
      currVal: input,
      prevVal: this.state.prevVal.concat(this.state.currVal),
      display: this.state.prevVal.concat(this.state.currVal).concat(input),
      expression: this.state.prevVal.concat(this.state.currVal).concat(input)
    
  })
  }
  
  handleEvaluate = input => {
    this.setState({
      display: input
    })
  }
  
  clearDisplay() {

    this.setState({
      prevVal: '',
      currVal: '',
      display: '0'
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id='display'>{this.state.display}</div>
        <Equals exp = {this.state.expression} handleClick = {this.handleEvaluate}/> 
        {this.state.numPad.map(num => 
                              <NumPad dig={num.dig} wrd={num.wrd} handleClick={this.handleDisplay}/>)}
        {this.state.operations.map(op => 
                              <Operations sym={op.sym} wrd={op.wrd} handleClick={this.handleDisplay}/>)}
        <button id='decimal'>.</button>
        <button id='clear' onClick={this.clearDisplay}>Clear</button>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I press the equals sign I get the same expression back.  I have tried passing `'this.props.exp'` and `this.props.exp.toString()` into the `eval()` function but it is still giving me the same string back without evaluating it.

Comment: appreciate the help but I just found the answer, thanks!

Comment: Since `exp` is an array, I think you want `eval(this.props.exp.join(""))`. Beware that `eval` is very much frowned upon and can be an easily exploited security hole. See [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: Appreciate the warning!  To be honest I am just trying to pass the tests for freecodecamp and I am weak with regex patterns so eval() seemed easier.  I don't think I will use it again considering the warnings

Comment: You don't need regex. I would have each operator assigned to a function, eg `"+": (l, r) => l + r, "-": (l, r) => l - r, ...`. There are probably many JS calculator references around that don't use `eval()`

Comment: oh that is interesting.  Maybe when I hit an operator the current number in the display can get stored in the l variable, and when I hot equals whatever is after the operator can get stored in the r variable

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, i should specify that expression is based on an array of values created by clicking buttons with 0-9 and the 4 basic expressions.  I then pass that array into the `eval()` function using `this.props.exp.join("")`.  I was using `toString()` forgeting that it puts commas between all the elements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).